# How can I use a model trained with the transformers trainer in the spaCy pipeline?

Tags: spacy, huggingface-transformers, spacy-transformers

I have trained and saved a BERT model for NER with the transformers trainer. Is it possible to use this model in the spaCy pipeline?

I have tried with `spacy.load('path\to\model')`, but get the following error:

OSError: [E053] Could not read meta.json

How can I use this model in the spacy pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spaCy uses `spacy-transformers` to wrap HuggingFace Transformers, but it only allows using the models as a source of features, it doesn't allow using task-specific heads like NER. So there's not an easy way to use this in spaCy.

If you want to load your model as a source of features, see the guide [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/10768) on how to specify your filename.

Another option is to load your HuggingFace model separately and wrap it as a spaCy component, but that's kind of involved and usually not very useful.